# Asking for more facebook user permissions only for "admins" in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

I'm making a webpage with facebook where there are simple users and admins. Admins can post articles to the webpage, and when they do that, it gets posted to a facebook page's wall. This feature is working, but i'm having some issues with the dynamic facebook permissions.

In my omniauth.rb i modified:

- `:scope =>...." to ":setup => true`
- and i added `match '/auth/facebook/setup' => 'authentications#setup_fb'` into my routes

However when I'm testing the page, the setup_fb method doesn't get called (I've put logger.info inside it and nothing happening). How can i fix it, or what do you think the problem is?

My only idea is that the "devise sessions" have something to do with it, because i have:

`devise_for ...:controllers => {:sessions => 'sessions'}`

I'm using omniauth-facebook, devise. and i'm a rails newbie :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Dynamic Permissions vs Setup Phase

#### Dynamic Permissions

So, it sounds like you are shooting for dynamic permissions, which it looks like you already have that setup correctly via your `:scope => ...` assuming that looks something like this

```
:scope => 'email,user_events,user_location,user_birthday'
```

#### Setup Phase

So with that said, by passing :setup => true, you're telling omniauth to initiate the [setup phase](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Setup-Phase), which is turned off by default.

I'm thinking that, based on your question, if dynamic permissions are what are trying to accomplish, your `:scope => ...` achieves that. Just remove `:setup => true` and let your callback flow continue as normal without interrupting it with the setup phase.

#### Devises Omniauth Callbacks

I'm going to assume that you are still needing to setup the callback phase.

A common way to do this using Devise is to alter your `config/routes.rb` file to define custom callback controllers, like so:

```
devise_for ... controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks'}
```

So yours will look something like

```
devise_for ... controllers: {:sessions => 'sessions', :omniauth_callbacks => 'omniauth_callbacks'}
```

You'll need to create the controller `app/controllers/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb`and define the facebook action. The Controller should also inherit from Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController. Something like this

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    ... # Do awesome user lookup/sign_in/redirect stuffs
    ... # request.env['omniauth.auth'] holds the returned information your :scope requested 
  end
end
```

That should solve your redirect problem. If you did intend to use setup phase, let me know and I can revise my answer.

Comment: Basically in this solution i can only have one "type of facebook permission" scope, since if i define my scope that way i already get the access_token when i have to check whenever the user needs "manage_pages" permission or not. Am i right? (i only want to ask for manage_pages token from admins)
My problem is that i need to log in that user, check if its an admin or not and then append the manage_pages permission to the scope and get a new access token.
Anyways i voted your answer, thanks for your explanation.

Comment: [Second half :)]
BTW meantime i realised maybe the simpliest way to do this is with an AJAX call:
(1) user logs in -> doc.rdy.fnct on mainpage or admin specific page
(2) #{ if user is admin } proceed with more ajax
(3) window.location.url = /auth/facebook?scope=manage_pages
Do you think it's an acceptable solution?